# CIFS VFS: Server xxx has not responded in 120 seconds

Tags: 13.10, windows, cifs

I am having a problem with a Windows mount that becomes unavailable and hang any process accessing it.

Doing a `dmesg` gives this:

```
[ 1566.033468] CIFS VFS: Server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
```

But nothing happens.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 in Virtual Box 4.3.4 that runs in Windows.

When I reboot, everything works fine for a bit. When I stop accessing the mount point for 15-30 minutes, I get the error.

I found the following information: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2113218 but it did not help.

Also found bugs in samba: https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9356 & it links to bug #9422 also.

Not sure if it is related.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: I have a similar problem, mine occurs while writing to the CIFS mount. When enabling logging with `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI` it becomes clear that while writing large files, the connection to the server can be lost; it can take multiple tries (each try is done after 120 seconds) for it to reconnect, after which the writing resumes. Meanwhile the process cannot be killed. With Google, it can be found that this problem is reported as far back as 2004, but the advertised resolutions don't work for me. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

I find that this happens when underlying storage is very slow. I have VM which has problems with the SAN timing out and i see these messages on regular bases. What is you setup VM or physical servers?